# Exchange differentiation with integration: $E[f'(X)/f(X)X]$

Tags: probability, integration, derivatives, expected-value, density-function

Let $X$ be a random variable with p.d.f. $f(x)$ (absolutely continuous and differentiable everywhere) and let $s(x)$ be the density score, i.e., $s(x) = d\log f(x)/ d x = f'(x)/f(x)$. Assume $\int |x| f(x)dx < \infty$, why is the following calculation nonsense?
$$
\begin{align}
E[s(X)X] &= \int  \frac{f'(x)}{f(x) }x f(x) dx 
= \int f'(x) x dx \\
&= \int \frac{d}{dx} f(x) x dx
= \frac{d}{dx} \int f(x)xdx \\
&= \frac{d}{dx} E[X]
= 0.
\end{align}
$$
This must be wrong, because I know if $X$ is a standard normal random variable, then $f'(x) = -x f(x)$, thus $E[s(X)X] = E[-X^2] = -E[X^2] = -1 \neq 0$. I know that the problem is the exchange of differentiation with integration, but what is wrong with the standard normal random variable such that the exchange is not permitted?

I appreciate any help!

Comment: When can you exchange integrals and derivatives ? Typically in the case where the upper bound of integration is the variable you differentiate with respect to. This is not your case here, the integral is over the whole domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a correct computation, assuming $f$ is continuously differentiable, strictly positive, and $|x|f(x) \to 0$ as $x \to \pm \infty$:

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{E}[s(X)X]
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} x f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x
= \int_{\mathbb{R}} x f'(x) \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \left[ xf(x) \right]_{-\infty}^{\infty} - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= -1,
\end{align*}

where we utilized integration by part in the second line. As per your mistake, in general

$$ \int \frac{\mathrm{d}u(x)}{\mathrm{d}x} v(x) \, \mathrm{d}x
\quad\neq\quad
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \int u(x) v(x) \, \mathrm{d}x. $$

This is evident if you differentiate both side:

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \text{[LHS]} = u'(x) v(x), \qquad \text{whereas}\qquad \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \text{[RHS]} = u'(x) v(x) + u(x) v'(x). $$

Comment: That is a very nice demo of the power of integration by parts! Thank you very much!!